# Is it possible to run multiple VPSes on a dedicated server with single public ip?

Tags: web-hosting, vps, dedicated-hosting, webmin

I have a dedicated server that I would like to split into multiple VPSes using KVM, I installed [cloudmin](https://www.virtualmin.com/about-cloudmin/) and created a KVM instance but I don't understand how to access the VPS from outside and link it to a domain if I only have one public IP that is configured for the dedicated server, is this possible? if so how does it work?

Comment: The DNS is used to map names to IP address, and multiple names can map to a single IP address. Then on top of TCP the HTTP(S) protocol starts the exchange with the client specifying the hostname it wants to access, hence allowing multiplexing or as it is called there, name based virtual hosting.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the appropriate forum (i'd have thought serverfault would cover this stuff better), but even if it is, Its not really possible to give a specific answer as the answer depends heavily on your deployment - including how you have set up networking, if you can run a VPN, and what you are using the instances for.  (If its for multiple web sites, you will need to make one VPS (or the bare metal) a reverse proxy, and having multiple VPS's may not be a good strategy.

Comment: FWIW, I have a KVM server with multiple VM's but a single public IP - however it is for a use case that does not need multiple public web servers, and I use a VPN if I'm connecting remotely to access the web interfaces on the various VM's.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Name based virtual hosting works on a single machine, but I've never heard of it used to farm requests out to different VMs.  Is that a real thing?  Can each VM listen on the same IP/port just for specific host names?

Comment: VM typically run on their own internal IP addresses that are then bridged or NATed to the outside world through the host. You can have an HTTP level proxy like HAProxy or Nginx to split incoming requests to internal backends being on multiple VMs based on various criterias (random, or weighted, etc.) Anyway not sure of the question now anymore really, so let us wait for proper replies.